# Why can't window.location.reload be passed as a first class function?

Tags: javascript

Why is it that this works,

```
setTimeout(function() { window.location.reload() }, 3000);
```

but this doesn't?

```
setTimeout(window.location.reload, 3000);
```

I receive the following error: `TypeError: 'reload' called on an object that does not implement interface Location.`

Comment: execution context. you'll find this is true for any member function. you need to bind the execution context `setTimeout(window.location.reload,bind(window.location), 3000);`. that should do it

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon except that first comma should be a dot.

Comment: yes you are right, typo

Answer (score 7):

In theory it can be. When you pass it like that, it is just the function, without its execution context (`this`). Since the function (internally) makes use of `this`, it fails. You may notice this with `console.log` as well.

The solution is to bind the context:

```
setTimeout(window.location.reload.bind(window.location), 3000);
```